# Use conditional in workflow in Nextflow dsl2

Tags: nextflow

How should I do:

```
...
if ($(params.aligner) == "bowtie") {
    align_bowtie2(get_fq_info.out.fq_info)
}
else {
    align_bwa(get_fq_info.out.fq_info)
}
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move that into your [workflow definition](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/dsl2.html#workflow-definition). There's an example in the docs of how best to use [workflow parameters](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/dsl2.html#workflow-parameters):

> A workflow component can access any variable and parameter defined in
> the outer scope:
>
> ```
> params.data = '/some/data/file'
>
> workflow my_pipeline {
>     if( params.data )
>         bar(params.data)
>     else
>         bar(foo()) }
> ```

Your example workflow would look like:

````
workflow {

    fq_info = get_fq_info.out.fq_info

    if( params.aligner == "bowtie" ) {
        align_bowtie2( fq_info )
    }
    else {
        align_bwa( fq_info )
    }

    ...
}
```
````

Answer (score 2):

Is this inside the `main.nf` file or inside the `process.nf` file? Anyway, the `param.anything` variable should already be available in the `nextflow` context when executed, thus, you could simply do:

```bash
if (params.aligner == "bowtie") {
    align_bowtie2(get_fq_info.out.fq_info)
} else {
    align_bwa(get_fq_info.out.fq_info)
}
```

Check out this [`main.nf`](https://github.com/fmalmeida/bacannot/blob/master/main.nf) of a nextflow pipeline of mine, it contains some working if/else snippets.

> Here it is [another StackOverflow question on conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50443545/conditional-pipeline-in-nextflow) nextflow pipelines that might help.

Hope it helps.